# casting a type Object to generic

Tags: java, generics, casting, quicksort

I know this is a very sloppy quicksort, but it is the one I am required to use.

My question is how to  change the type of the `y` array to type `E` on line `x[k+i]=(E) (y[k])`. The way I'm currently doing does not cast object as type `E`. The quicksort works fine (at least before the recursion), it's just the casting at this point.

```
public class quicksort {
    static <E extends Comparable<E>> E[] quickSort(E[] x, int i, int j) {
        int pivot = 0;
        Object[] y = new Object[j - i + 1];
        for (int k = 0; k < y.length; k++) y[k] = x[k + i];
        int lput = i;
        int rput = j;
        for (int k = i + 1; k <= j; k++) {
            if (x[k].compareTo(x[pivot]) < 0) {
                y[(lput++) - i] = x[k];
            } else {
                y[(rput--) - i] = x[k];
            }
        }

        pivot = lput;
        y[lput - i] = pivot;
        for (int k = 0; k < y.length; k++)
            x[k + i] = (E) (y[k]); // this line
        quickSort(x, i, pivot - 1);
        quickSort(x, pivot + 1, j);
        System.out.println("got here");
        return x;
    }
}
```

Here is the stack trace. the line refer to is `x[k + i] = (E) (y[k])`;

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to E

at quicksort.quickSort(quicksort.java:23)
at ArrayListGui$6.actionPerformed(ArrayListGui.java:158)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: How does it not work precisely? Do you get an error?

Comment: i get a type mismatch cannot convert object to type E

Comment: That's the thing - `y` is an `Object` array, not an array of `E`. Try using a `Collection` instead.

Comment: Object is no Subtype of Comparable, so the compiler cant cast that for you, i think

Comment: Post the complete stack trace of the exception. And tell us which line it refers to. Note that you're storing an int into your object array here: `y[lput - i] = pivot`. This is certainly wrong.

Comment: so you're saying use collections instead of the quicksort

Comment: I assume you're required to implement quicksort - collections instead of arrays, because you can type them in this case. If you aren't required to implement quicksort, then use the built in sorts.

Comment: i am required to use this specific quicksort

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a generic array in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java)

Comment: Just create `y` as a generic-typed array instead. See the dupe I linked.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is already the most correct way to do it. It compiles and works fine.

An alternative way would be to create the array as:

```
E[] y = (E[])new Comparable[j - i + 1];
```

and then when you get it out, you wouldn't have to cast it:

```
x[k + i] = (E) (y[k]);
```

However, this is kind of dangerous because the actual runtime class of the object pointed to `y` is `Comparable[]`, *not* `E[]`, and if you accidentally expose `y` to the outside of the method as type `E[]`, it can lead to crashes in other pieces of code, which is unexpected. In this method, you are not exposing `y` to the outside of the method, so it won't cause any problems in this case.

Answer (score -2):

You can do it by passing a [*type token*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type%E2%80%93token_distinction), which can then be used to create an instance of a typed using the JDK's [`Array.newInstance(Class<?> componentType, int length)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance-java.lang.Class-int-) factory method:

```
static <E extends Comparable<E>> E[] quickSort(Class<E> clazz, E[] x, int i, int j) {
    E[] y = (E[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, j - i + 1);
    ...
}
```

Comment: I am curious to know why ppl don't like this answer. It compiles and solves the problem.